# Search Multiple Fields with one keyword input in a form with other field searches

Tags: low-search

I've seen variants of this question but nothing that matches. There is a form that has multiple dropdown category selectors and a few keyword inputs. This is the field which I would like to also search the entry title.

```
<input type="text" name="search:resource_additional_names:rhn_historical_name" value="{low_search_keywords}" placeholder="Keywords">
```

If I try something like:

```
<input type="text" name="search:resource_additional_names:rhn_historical_name|search:title" value="{low_search_keywords}" placeholder="Keywords">
```

The results page throws an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might want to post this question on Low's specific support forum for Low Search - here: http://getsatisfaction.com/low - he's pretty good at responding promptly to questions etc.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a new collection with only the fields I wanted to search and use a keyword input:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="{low_search_keywords}">
```

I had to make sure the collection is referenced in the search and results pages and more importantly, one of the fields I needed to search was a Matrix field and the column that was to be searched needed to have "Is col searchable?" checked and then all entries needed to be resaved.